# Calling delphi procedure from C++

Tags: c++, delphi

I have a DLL written in Delphi that I need to call from a C++ code. The signature of the procedure in Delphi is:

```
procedure GetDeviceName(     No: integer;
                           Name: PChar;
                            Len: integer;
                      var Error: integer); stdcall;
```

From the code from the DLL I believed that I could call it with this block of code:

```
typedef void (__stdcall *GetDeviceNamePtr)(int, char*, int, int*);

GetDeviceNamePtr GetDeviceName = (GetDeviceNamePtr) GetProcAddress(m, "GetDeviceName");

char DeviceName[256];
int Error;
GetDeviceName(1, DeviceName, 256, &Error);
```

However, I've got an access violation. Should the last parameter of the procedure signature be a pointer to an integer or an integer ? I'm confused about the "var" keyword in the declaration of the procedure. I've checked the exported symbols of DLL and the procedure considered is properly exported. What's wrong in my procedure ?

Some more info regarding the environment:

1. It's a dll compiled with delphi 6.
2. ANSI only.
3. I'm debugging on the C++ side and the exception is right on the call to the function.
4. Nothing is returned from the function calling the DLL API.

Comment: The first obvious test for me would be to provide an array big enough (256 bytes), but only tell 128 (or even only 64) as length parameter and then to look what is written to it.

Comment: The code shown looks OK to me. What does the AccessViolation error message actually say, verbatim? Did you validate that `GetProcAddress()` is not returning a `NULL` pointer? What does the code inside the DLL look like? Please edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: You could debug your DLL with Delphi: In the DLL project, set "host application" as your C++ application. Put a break point in your function and run. Delphi will load the C++ application which in turn load the DLL. Then Delphi debugger will stop on the breakpoint in the DLL and from there you can single step in Delphi code an understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the fairly small amount of information you have provided, my initial thought is that you have declared the array `DeviceName` as a local variable so it's on the stack, and then overrun the stack giving you an AV when you try to return.

- In modern versions of Delphi, `Char` is `wchar_t` and `PChar` is `wchar_t*` (so a `Len` of 256 might either mean 256 bytes or 128 characters).
- `var` in the prototype indicates a parameter passed by reference, so I would expect `int*`.
- Have you checked for variable sizes in the version of Delphi the DLL is written in and the calling application? If they think that `Integer` and `int` are different sizes (32bit vs. 64bit) your pointers will be garbage.
- Are you able to step into the DLL in your debugger? If you can look at how the variables are being assigned when you enter the routine that should identify if you are passing what it expects.
- And as a final thought - are you sure the Delphi DLL actually works? (I have been caught out by this before, and you could spend days on something that's not your problem!)

Comment: Technically, `var Error: integer` would translate as `int &Error` in C++. But `int *Error` will work, too (that is what C would need to use). But in any case, Delphi and C++ both use 32bits for the size of `Integer`/`int`, respectvely

Comment: I've got the same exception when increasing the size of the buffer. I'm expecting to be a problem around the last point of your answer: [Rob Lambden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10879061/rob-lambden)

Comment: @rbw then the problem has to be inside the DLL itself, but you have not shown that code yet. Please edit your question to add that.